# Find all files older than one minute

Tags: linux, find

How can I use `find` to select files that have been written and not modified in the last minute?

I know I can do it the other way around, find files modified in the last 60 seconds with `-mtime -60s`, but I want the ones that haven't been modified in the last 60 seconds.

I use Linux and get this error if I use seconds:

```
find ??/ -mtime +60s -name blah.tsv
find: invalid argument `+60s' to `-mtime'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `find /path -type f -mtime +60s`

The `-` just before the digits is not a regular "argument dash", but means "less than". `+` then is "more than".

From `man find`:

> All primaries which take a numeric argument allow the number to be preceded by a plus sign (``+'') or a minus sign (``-'').  A preceding plus sign means ``more than n'', a preceding minus sign means ``less than n'' and neither means ``exactly n''.

It should be noted that for *exactly n*, the time is rounded. So `1` (1 day) does not mean 86400 seconds.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `+60` is not the opposite of `-60`, for the same reason *less than* is not the opposite of *greater than*: Both exclude the exact value they compare to. But your question does not indicate which behavior you want, exactly.

Comment: This isn't exactly the same indeed, since ! reverts the original "query". But agreed, the OP doesn't specify what he wants.

Comment: The day after, the OP stated it is on Linux, not Mac OS X. If that would have changed the answer, can you update it?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work on Linux.  At least RHEL 5.6.  SiegeX's response below does work, however.

Comment: @khaki54 Yeah, it's a bit confusing. While the user states that he uses Linux in an edit, he/she uses OS X/BSD find syntax in the second paragraph to the question ("*I know I can do … with `-mtime -60s`*") and has accepted this as the best answer...

Comment: This doesn't work on CentOS. As supposed it works in Mac OS X

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -type f -mmin +1
```

#### Example

```
$ ls *
four.txt  one.txt  three.txt  two.txt

$ touch foo && find . -mmin +1
.
./three.txt
./four.txt
./two.txt
./one.txt
```

Comment: It is no longer tagged with `osx`.

Answer (score 4):

### The second `-` in `-mtime -60s` is *not* an option delimiter.

`-mtime` is an option, and it is followed by an *option argument*.  The option argument is `-60s`, and the `-` in it is part of the option argument itself, *not* an option delimiter.  It means "less than 60 seconds".  Option arguments `60s` and `+60s` mean "equal to 60 seconds" and "greater than 60 seconds", respectively.

The Apple MacOS manual and the FreeBSD manual mention the `+` and `-` prefixes in exactly one place, and forget to explain anywhere what they are.  This is what they are.

(The GNU Info manual for GNU `find` has the same omission, interestingly enough.  However, GNU `find`'s syntax for times is somewhat different to the BSD and MacOS `find` syntax.)

#### Further reading

- Apple incorporated (2008-02-24). [*`find` MacOS 10 manual page*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html).  MacOS 10 Developer Library.
- [*`find`(1)*](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE).  2010-03-17. FreeBSD General Commands Manual. FreeBSD Project.

Comment: It's even worse than just explaining it in *exactly one place*: All other options refer to `atime` for the time format, but *that does also not explain the prefixes*. It's a separate section that isn't referenced.

Comment: Indeed; and you'll find that I wrote that.  I wrote "mention", and "forget to explain anywhere".  ☺

Comment: I didn't mean to contradict you, just wanted to point out that the *exactly one place* is also *the worst possible place* from a "let's just skim the man page" POV.

Comment: But it _isn't_ explained in exactly one place.  It's not explained in any place at all.  For a set of manual pages that is generally written and edited fairly well, in my experience, it's a surprising omission.

Comment: See my answer. There is actually a place where it's explained (unfortunately in very  abstract terms), but it's not part of the `atime` explanation or referenced there.

Comment: Heh!  That's because you magically know the answer already and can connect the twain when reading the document, filling in what isn't actually written.  The people who don't have (y)our foreknowledge and are reading the manual in order to find out have to wonder why there's no explanation of what a "modifier" is anywhere.  ☺

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use

```
find . ! -mtime -60s
```

Comment: Requires parenthesis for me: `find . !( -mtime -60s )`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: On my Mac, it works OK without the parenthesis (Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

In Unix systems -mtime used to be followed by a +/- followed by a number followed by units of time. 
[+-]nn[dms]

Linux uses mtime for days, mmin for minutes, but there doesn't seem to be a seconds option and doesn't use a time units specifier. 
The + or - still refers to greater than or less than the time rather than be a option argument as mentioned above.

You could use -mmin 1, but https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238738/find-files-newer-than-15-seconds-but-older-than-2-seconds discusses how to handle seconds in general.