# Linux setuid programs/files

Tags: linux, setuid

how to find files based upon time information, such as creation, modified and accessed. It is useful to find files before a certain time, after a certain time and between two times. what command in Linux would i have to use ?

I understand to find setuid files on linux computers i would have to use :

> find / -xdev ( -perm -4000 ) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l

How do i check for files which have been modified in the last 30 minutes. (I created a new file called FILE2)

Comment: First of all, you are on the right track with find. Reread it manual page: find also has atime, mtime and others, which will do what you asked. 
Also check out [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days) on our sister site as well as [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/383123/find-all-files-older-than-one-minute)

Comment: Secondly: Why are you using `-print0` piped though `xargs -0`?
Do you want or need the specific `ls -l` format? 

If you just need the file names and permissions then there are also many other options in find itself. E.g. `find /path -ls`, or some of the GNU find extensions which allows complex looking but powerful stuff like `printf "%M %u %g %s\t%Ab %Ad %AH:%AM\t%Cb %Cd %CH:%CM\t%P\n"`

Answer (score 0):

> How do i check for files which have been modified in the last 30 minutes

```
find /path -type f -mmin -30
```

- `-30` if you want files modified 30 minutes or less
- `30` if you want files modified exactly 30 minutes ago
- `+30` if you want files that were modified more than 30 minutes ago

This would search for files modified between 30 and 45 minutes ago

```
find /path -type f -mmin +30 -mmin -45
```